# What makes safe call (question mark) to be interpreted differently from classic if?

Tags: if-statement, kotlin, nullable, kotlin-null-safety

In *Kotlin*, if we declare a class member as **var** and **nullable** type, compiler doesn't allow us to run the member function although we put an if statement before calling the function because the compiler can't guarantee that the member isn't been set to null after checking against null and before calling the method.
**But** if we are using a *safe call* compiler approves our code.
My question, how the compiler makes the safe call atomic? Isn't a second thread can change the variable between checking for null and calling the method (eat method in the example)?
Code for first situation:

```
        class MyWolf
{
    var w : Wolf? = Wolf()
    
    fun myFunction()
    {
        if (w != null)
        {
            w.eat()
        }
    }

}

class Wolf
{
    fun eat() : Unit
    println("wolf is eating")
}
```

Code for second situation:

```
    class MyWolf
{
    var w : Wolf? = Wolf()
        
    fun myFunction()
    {
        w?.eat()
    }
}

class Wolf
{
      fun eat():Unit
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Kotlin \`?.let\` thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324180/is-kotlin-let-thread-safe)

Comment: Since i don't understand the answer i can't say :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler puts the contents of the field to the local variable and then compares it with null. You can clearly see it if you decompile Kotlin bytecode.

Comment: Ok. nice to know. unfortunately i don't know how to read bytecode

Comment: @Eitanos30 it creates a number of nested `if`s. In each `if` it calculates the next value, puts it to the local variable, and compares with null.

Comment: @Eitanos30 as for Kotlin bytecode - it's easy to see and decompile it to the more readable Java from Android Studio. Just go to Tools->Kotlin->"Show Kotlin Bytecode" and press "Decompile"

Comment: Raspopopv, When saying *puts the contents of the field to the local variable*, do you mean a copy of the object is saved into a local variable?

Comment: @Eitanos30 it doesn't create a copy, just putting the reference to the same object to the local variable.

Comment: @ Konstantin Raspopov, thanks  a lot! i understand!